# How to stop tensorflow data generator from consuming all the memory?

Tags: keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Keras model that takes in a sequence of images and predicts one.

```
#Input shape: (#samples,seq_length,image_height,image_width,1)
#Output shape: (#samples,seq_length,image_height,image_width,1)
```

I have written the number of samples to a file-server. The total memory it takes is around ~1TB.

Following is how I have approached the problem:

```
def gen_x():
  for filename in os.listdir("data_X"):
      with open ("data_X/"+filename, 'rb') as fp:
          X = pickle.load(fp)
      yield X

def gen_y():
  for filename in os.listdir("data_Y"):
      with open ("data_Y/"+filename, 'rb') as fp:
          Y = pickle.load(fp)
      yield Y      

ds_x=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_x, (tf.float32), (tf.TensorShape([50,128,64,1]))).batch(128)
ds_y=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen_y, (tf.float32), (tf.TensorShape([5,128,64,1]))).batch(128)

it_x = ds_x.make_one_shot_iterator()
it_y = ds_y.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

The model however when starts training, consumes all the memory available, instead of allocating memory just for the batch. Note that the GPU memory remains under-utilized, but the RAM is completely exhausted. Following is the code for the model:

```
input_frames=Input(tensor=it_x.get_next())
x=ConvLSTM2D(filters=40, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', return_sequences=False)(input_frames)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv2D(filters=5,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same")(x)
x=Reshape((5,128,64,1))(x)
model=Model(inputs=input_frames,outputs=x)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adadelta',target_tensors=[it_y.get_next()])    
model.fit(steps_per_epoch=#Samples // 128, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```